# Android - Check the phone number type

Tags: android

I'd like to update the contacts in my phone according to a certain logic. When I write them back to the database, I have to determine the type under which it is stored using the for example for mobile contact.

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE`

```
// Number mobile       
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)});
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
ops.add(builder.build());
```

I want to put in a switch case to be able to check for the appropriate type from either:
`TYPE_WORK`
`TYPE_HOME`
 `TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN`
  `TYPE_ASSISTANT`
  `TYPE_ISDN`

but I'm a little clueless on what key to use. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you want to put in your own DB or andoid Db?

Comment: I want to put it in the android Db. The app just updates the contacts from the ContactsContract content provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use int type:

```
int number_type; // the type of phone no. to update
switch(number_type)
{
 case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
    // your code for update..
  break;
 case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
    // and so on....
  break;
}
```